# Multiple DB Instance connection with SqlAlchemy Core

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Im trying to make a multiple database connection. Right now im able to generate a single engine connection for multiple databases. This works by having for my main database (Shared database) defined in mainschema.py (alias dbm):

```
mymetadata = MetaData()

Base = declarative_base(metadata=mymetadata)

class newbase(DeferredReflection, Base):
    __abstract__ = True

table_args = {
        'mysql_engine': dict_constants['sql_mainDB_engine'],
        'mysql_charset': dict_constants['sql_mainDB_collation'],
        'schema' : 'smv',
    }

class Company(newbase):
__tablename__ = 'companies'
__table_args__ = table_args

id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
company = Column(String(255))
db = Column(String(255))
enabled = Column(BOOLEAN, nullable=False)
```

Then for each client i will have a specific database defined in dbschema.py (alias dbc)

```
mymetadata = MetaData()

Base = declarative_base()

table_args = {
        'mysql_engine': dict_constants['sql_mainDB_engine']
    }


# __abstract__ causes declarative to skip the production of a table or mapper for the class entirely
class newbase(DeferredReflection, Base):
    __abstract__ = True


#Creating Base Classes

class ObjectGroup(newbase):
    __tablename__ = 'objectgroups'
    __table_args__ = table_args

    id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(30), unique=True, nullable=False)
    parentobjectgroup_id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), ForeignKey(id,onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="RESTRICT"), nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DATETIME, nullable=False)
    updated_at = Column(DATETIME, nullable=False)
    enabled = Column(BOOLEAN, nullable=False)
```

After that i create the engine:

```
self.clientconnection   = '%s://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?charset=%s&use_unicode=0' % (self.dict_constants['sql_clientDB_driver'],
                                                                  self.dict_constants['sql_clientDB_user'], self.dict_constants['sql_clientDB_passwd'],
                                                                  host, port, db, self.dict_constants['sql_mainDB_collation'])
self.engine = create_engine(self.clientconnection, echo=False, pool_size=1, pool_timeout=30)

self.base = dbc.newbase

#opening several threads on the same time produces error in prepare, only one at a time

with sema_clientengine:
        try:
            self.base.prepare(self.engine)
```

example of a query:

```
position_table = dbc.Position.__table__
position = alias(position_table, name='position', flat=True)
filter = and_(position.c.object_id == objectid, position.c.validpos == 1)
query = select([position]).where(filter).order_by(position.c.moment_id.desc()).limit(1)
```

This is how i read:

```
    with sema_reads:
        debug_starttime = time()
        try:
            self.engine.dispose()
            with self.engine.connect() as connection:
                proxyobject = connection.execute(query)
```

Okay so basically i have in a same instance one main database called 'smv' and for each client a indepent DB.

So when i create an engine and ran a connect depending on the class it will go to the defined schema. This works great, i can even make joins between databases. Now i need to put the main database 'smv' on a different DB instance so i can scale up and here is when everything stops working because the shared engine only connects to the clients instance and now the smv schema doesnt exist.

Any ideas?

Added on 2019-02-05:

Okay so after some testing i could make it work with sessions, notice that Company table is not just in a different database than Objects, its on a different database instance, different IP and Port:

```
config_1 = {
    "sqlalchemy.url": "%s://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" % (dict_constants['sql_mainDB_driver'], dict_constants['sql_mainDB_user'],
                                                     dict_constants['sql_mainDB_passwd'], dict_constants['sql_mainDB_host'],
                                                     dict_constants['sql_mainDB_port'], dict_constants['sql_mainDB_name']),
    "sqlalchemy.echo": False,
}

config_2 = {
    "sqlalchemy.url": "%s://%s:%s@%s:3307/clientdb" % (dict_constants['sql_mainDB_driver'], dict_constants['sql_mainDB_user'],
                                                     dict_constants['sql_mainDB_passwd'], dict_constants['sql_mainDB_host']),
    "sqlalchemy.echo": False,
}

engine_1 = engine_from_config(config_1)
engine_2 = engine_from_config(config_2)

Base = declarative_base()
Base2 = declarative_base()

class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'companies'


    id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
    company = Column(String(255))
    db = Column(String(255))
    enabled = Column(BOOLEAN, nullable=False)

class Object(Base2):
    __tablename__ = 'objects'

    id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(30), unique=True, nullable=False)
    objectgroup_id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), nullable=False)
    objectaction_id = Column(SMALLINT(unsigned=True), nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DATETIME, nullable=False)
    updated_at = Column(DATETIME, nullable=False)
    enabled = Column(BOOLEAN, nullable=False)


#session.configure(bind={Company:engine_1})

binds = {Base:engine_1, Base2:engine_2}

session = sessionmaker(binds=binds)
session = session()

print session.query(Company).all()

print session.query(Object).all()
```

So this works, but i need to ran more complex queries and for that for me ts better this way but it only works when i specify the engine. Any way that session detects it automatically depending on the table class?. Also is it possible to ran a join with tables from different database instance?

```
company = alias(Company.__table__, name='company', flat=True)
query = select([Company]).order_by(company.c.company)
proxyobject = session.execute(query, bind=engine_1)

rows = proxyobject.fetchall()

print rows
```

Comment: Maybe relevant, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12352483/5781248

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Interesting approach Thanks, but i think its still per connection approach. Im currently testing with sessions but its only working when i pass bind=engine:
   `Session = sessionmaker(binds={
    SomeMappedClass: create_engine('postgresql://engine1'),
    SomeDeclarativeBase: create_engine('postgresql://engine
2'),
    some_mapper: create_engine('postgresql://engine3'),
    some_table: create_engine('postgresql://engine4'),
    })`

found in [link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_2/orm/session_api.html?highlight=session%20api#module-sqlalchemy.orm.session).